# Ansible: How do I link Variables, stored in a Vault to a specific host?

Tags: ansible, ansible-vault

I want to encrypt my host credentials in a central secrets.yml file.

How can I tell Ansible, to use the variables?

I tried with this setup:

host_vars/test.yml

```
ansible_user: {{ test_user }}
ansible_become_pass: {{ test_pass }}
```

secrets.yml

```
# Credentials Test Server #

test_user: user
test_pass: password
```

inventory.yml

```
all:
  children: 
    test:
      hosts:
        10.10.10.10
```

playbook.yml

```
---
- name: Update Server
  hosts: test
  become: yes
  vars_files:
    - secrets.yml

  tasks:
    - name: Update
      ansible.builtin.apt:
        update_cache: yes
```

For execution I user this command:

```
ansible-playbook -i inventory.yml secure_linux.yml --ask-vault-pass
```

During execution I get this Error Message:

fatal: [10.10.10.10]: UNREACHABLE! => {"changed": false, "msg": "Failed to connect to the host via ssh: root@10.10.10.10: Permission denied (publickey,password).", "unreachable": true}

Answer (score 0):

For those credentials to be used by `all` hosts, use the `group_vars/all` directory.  So you will have the file `group_vars/all/secrets.yml`, which you will encrypt with `ansible-vault`.

```
ansible_user: user
ansible_password: password
```

You do not need a `host_vars` file.

Answer (score 0):

The solution was:

- give the host_vars file the right name (10.10.10.10.yml)
- add ansible_password as variable
- use quotation marks "{{ test_user }}"